# PHP .htaccess URL Rewriting

Tags: php, .htaccess, iis, mod-rewrite

Basically I'm a .net developer so I have no clue regarding this.

I have purchased a php script[site] and configured it over http://spicyindia.net/

eveything works fine when I append php to the file extension.

for eg works fine

> http://spicyindia.net/all.php

but

> http://spicyindia.net/all

fails

by some RND which I did there is a file named .htaccess which is responsible for this operations..

I have that file uploaded into hosting server too.

can some one tell me if there is any extra configuration which is needed for the same.

some lines in .htaccess .

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^login$ login.php
RewriteRule ^logout$ logout.php
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @hakre RND was to find out where why files are working with extension and not working without extension , as I'm totally new to PHP but I have .net experience I could lead to possibility of .htaccess file behind this.

Comment: And your programming question is? If you know nothing about this, why don't you first read about the topic? Otherwise your question might sound more like guessing than asking a programming question. No offence please, but the help section gives some good hints how to improve questions.

Comment: @hakre there is no need of being so rude, why do you think I have not read it it forums, its because stack overflow is a good place where you get really good answers which we can trust, I have come here to ask it, and please search stack overflow where people have enjoyed asking very very basic questions..you might be good at PHP.. but not everyone is, I'm just trying to seek help from people who are willing to offer it, if you dont want to help, just dont..

Comment: Please use the search then if basic questions is what you look for, we have many of them already covered: [htaccess is not working on iis](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7688714/367456) - and as written my last comment was not ment to be rude, please don't feel offended by my previous comment, as I already wrote in it.

Answer (score 3):

In your `.htaccess` file, try this to access all,

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Comment: Its just a sample lines which i have given, there are lot lines..in the same..

Comment: @Manish. Then you have to post it. If you are using this, you can access every page without ``.php extension``

Answer (score 2):

It rewrites only `login` and `logout`

Try using this one:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

It rewrites every `.php` file

Answer (score 1):

This will convert all `www.domain.com/xyz.php` to `www.domain.com/xyz`

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide `.php` extension then remove those 2 `RewriteRule` and have your .htaccess like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}/+\s(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

#### Reference: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)

Comment: I think it's worth if you start to link as well where the manual of Mod Rewrite is and where the regular expressions are documented within it and the the example section in that manual instead of just dumping .htaccess configuration one question after the other not explaining anything. I mean according to your reputation this is long-time overdue.

Comment: @hakre: Reference doc link added. But too be very honest most of the time new developer doesn't get much help from that reference doc even after going through it multiple times. (btw that link comes as top link in Google search) Besides I had provided proper reasoning and comments in my answer too. Would you really believe that deserved your -1 ?

Comment: hi @anubhava I uploaded the file making changes which you have suggested, but still the same issues, what do you think, is it related to IIS?

Comment: @Manish: Didn't know you're using IIS since it wasn't tagged same. Can you just try last rule in IIS?